# how to change the elements in odd positions?

Tags: r

[My table looks similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZzTo.png) I have a table with 15 rows and 6 columns. Let's say my column number 6 is patient's blood sugar; I want to multiply all elements that come on odd positions by 5 and leave the rest unchanged (only for that specific column). How can I do that?

if in odd positions then blood sugar * 5 ..... if in even position then leave unchanged

Thank you

Comment: I can many confusions going around answer to your question. It would be better if you can provide expected output for `BloodSugar` after multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming my data is `data`, I'll first create a vector to store all the indexes of odd rows within the `PatientProfile` dataframe:

```
odd_ind <-seq(1,nrow(PatientProfile),2)
odd_ind
# returns: 1   3   5   7   9  11  13  15
```

And then subset for rows in `odd_ind`, and multiply 5 to the value of `value` in those qualifying rows:

```
PatientProfile[odd_ind, "BloodSugar"] <- PatientProfile[odd_ind, "BloodSugar"] *5
```

Comment: @r_beginner try the code I provide `PatientProfile[even_ind, "BloodSugar"] <- PatientProfile[even_ind, "BloodSugar"] *5`. This should work on the dataset based on the screenshot of your table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually need to multiply odd positions by 5; not even! What does even_ind stand for?

Comment: @r_beginner fixed the code for you. Copy and run the three lines I gave you and it will work. `odd_ind` is just a vector of odds numbers going from 1 to 15 for a dataframe that has a row of 16 or less (hence `nrow(PatientProfile)`)

Comment: It worked for me xoxo

Comment: please accept the answer @r_beginner and glad it helped you! Was my explanations about what `odd_ind` clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical index with `%%` that gives TRUE for odd and FALSE for even positions.  Then subset the 6th column rows based on that and assign the modified values by multiplying with 5

```
i1 <- as.logical(seq_len(nrow(df1)) %% 2)
df1[[6]][i1] <- df1[[6]][i1] * 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-data.frame('x'=rnorm(15),
               'y'=rnorm(15))

## tag odd row position 

df$odd.row<-as.numeric(row.names(df))%%2

## change the column, say x, base on odd.row
df$x.changed<-ifelse(df$odd.row ==1, df$x*5, df$x)
```

Hope this would solve your problem, there may be a better way to do this, more elegantly and efficiently, someone else may know how to that. By the way,  whenever you have a problem, search for an answer before simply post a question, provide a minimum reproducible example if a complete search did not help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion but it turned my values into (1,0) then my new column gave me weird decimal numbers

Comment: That's why you should provide a reproducible example. `$` is to create a new column, make sure you follow exactly the steps I posted. However, if other solutions did solve your problem, forget mine and accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use seq to index every other row:

```
# dummy data
df <-data.frame("x" = LETTERS[1:10], "h" = sample(c("M", "F"), replace = T, size = 10), "y" = sample(seq(1, 3, 1), replace = T, size = 10))


# index odd rows using seq
df[seq(1, length(df[,1]), 2), 3] <- df[seq(1, length(df[,1]), 2), 3] * 5
```

You've since commented asking whether you could use for loops or ifelse statements, yes you could (though I'm not sure why you would):

```
# for loop
for(i in seq(1, length(df[,1]), 2)){
  df[i,3] <- 5 * df[i,3]
}

# ifelse
library("gtools")
df[,3] <- ifelse(odd(as.numeric(rownames(df))), 5 * df[,3], df[,3])
```

Comment: Can I use if else or loops? Thanks

Comment: I tried every single suggestion on here, none of them worked for me. They absolutely sound gibberish to me "I LITERALLY CAN CRY AT THIS POINT" Can you please view the table I provided?

Comment: Looking at your table you are trying to multiply column 3: I'll update the code, check back in a minute

Comment: @r_beginner done - see all the 3's in my code - that's telling it which column to focus on

Comment: Yup, that is correct. I need to multiply 132 (location 1), 79 (location 3), 120 (location 5) , 89 (location 7), 139 (location 9)…… each by 5.

Comment: Nope ;(  What's library("gtools")? It's giving me error message... Also odd is giving me as undefined function

Comment: You need to install the package: `install.packages("gtools")`